# I am writing a program to read mm/dd/yyyy and am stuck on how to extract the mm from the string and turn it into an int

Tags: java, string, int, substring

Am I doing this wrong to start with or am I just not realizing something I need to do to turn the string into an int and find the month part?

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GoodDateBook

{
  public static void main(String[]args)

  {
    Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);

String allInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a date in the form mm/dd/yyyy");
String monthDayYear = kybd.nextLine();

int month2 = monthDayYear.indexOf("/");
int month = ?
```

Comment: its java not javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the input:

```
String monthDayYear = "09/19/2013";
String[] parts = monthDayYear.split("/");
int month = Integer.valueOf(parts[0]);
int day = Integer.valueOf(parts[1]);
int year = Integer.valueOf(parts[2]);
```

Comment: Thank you Tichodroma, that helped me out a lot. i now can move on to the next part of this. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    int mm = Integer.parseInt("09/19/2013".replaceAll(".+/(.+)/.+", "$1"));
```